# if decay rates were somehow increased, would neutron flux proportionally increase in a reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I've heard people argue that decay rates in the past could have been faster. Despite not having a mechanism for this, I am curious about it. The oklo reactor is commonly cited as proof that decay rates have not changed, but I'm wondering if just changing the decay rates, say 20% for each type of decay, if the neutron flux would proportionally increase to allow the reactor to work and give us the same byproducts (isotope ratios etc) and evidence that we have today

Comment: Note that most U-235 decays just emit alpha particles. Only $7×10^{-9}$% of the decays are spontaneous fission, which releases neutrons. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_uranium#List_of_isotopes Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_fraction

Comment: I'm kind of a layman, so I'm having trouble understanding/connecting the dots here. Are you saying that because only 7x10–⁹ percent of the decays are spontaneous fission, an increase in all of the decays wouldn't cause the necessary increase in neutron flux?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to consider both the decay rate and the branching fraction. If some mysterious mechanism changes the decay rate it may also change the branching fraction. Eg, if the decay rate doubled but the branching fraction halved, the neutron flux would be unchanged.

Comment: But would the decay rates being changed directly cause the branching factor to compensate and change as well to facilitate regular reactor function

Comment: To keep things simple, we can just assume that the branching factor is unchanged. According to standard physics, neither the decay rate nor branching factor change, so it's hard to guess what would happen to the branching factor if the decay rate *did* change for some mysterious reason.

Comment: Yeah I don't know if the branching factor - or anything else- is independent of an increase in decay rates